# Subtracting previous row to current row of timestamp datatype

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, jobs, job-scheduling

I need to subtract current REQ_START_DATE from ( previous ACTUAL_START_DATE + RUN_DURATION) in order to check the timing whether job is requested before completion of the previous execution.

Tried using below query:

```
WITH delay_in_start AS (
SELECT  LOG_ID, LOG_DATE, OWNER, JOB_NAME, REQ_START_DATE, ACTUAL_START_DATE,run_duration, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY job_name ORDER BY req_start_date desc) RN
FROM dba_scheduler_job_run_details t
)
SELECT cast(A.req_start_date as date) - cast((B.ACTUAL_START_DATE + b.run_duration)  as date) Consumption, a.*, b.*
FROM delay_in_start A LEFT JOIN delay_in_start B 
    ON B.JOB_NAME = A.JOB_NAME 
    AND A.RN  = B.RN - 1
    where cast(A.req_start_date as date) > (cast(B.ACTUAL_START_DATE as date) + b.run_duration)
```

But not sure of the output.

Can someone help?

Comment: What are you not sure about? You haven't shown any sample data, current output or expected output, so we don't have much to go on. (Also, look at the lag function to look at the previous row, rather than using a subquery with row number; you may find it simpler.)

Comment: lag function doesn't help in date datatype. Since dba_scheduler_job_run_details  is a view for jobs and exists globally hence I didnt provided sample. My requirement is to just calculate req_start_date of job (last execution) shouldn't be lesser then the actual_start_date + run_duration of job (second last execution)

Comment: You're wrong about lag, but that's kind of a side issue. You still haven't said what you are not sure about. Have you just got `>` instead of `<` in your where clause, if you only want to see those that overlapped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, you seem to be comparing the wrong way around; your where-clause filter is looking for requested dates *after* the completion of the previous job, based on its actual start time and duration - not before.

So you can perhaps just change the logic to:

```
where cast(A.req_start_date as date) < (cast(B.ACTUAL_START_DATE as date) + b.run_duration)
```

I'm not sure why you're casting the timestamps to dates though; you're losing precision, which could mean you miss jobs that ran very close together (sub-second gap). On my test instance I see 23 records with those casts - all from `ORACLE_APEX_MAIL_QUEUE` - but 36 if I leave them as timestamps.

You can also use `lag()` instead of self-joining based on row number:

```
select lag_actual_start_date + lag_run_duration - req_start_date as consumption,
  t.*
from (
  select dba_scheduler_job_run_details.*,
    lag(actual_start_date)
      over (partition by job_name order by req_start_date) as lag_actual_start_date,
    lag(run_duration)
      over (partition by job_name order by req_start_date) as lag_run_duration
  from dba_scheduler_job_run_details
) t
where req_start_date < lag_actual_start_date + lag_run_duration
order by job_name, req_start_date;
```

Which gives the 'consumption' as an interval - positive as I've switched the terms round in that subtraction too.

The results currently include only the actual start date and duration from the previous row; if you wanted other fields then you could include lag clauses for those too. I would also avoid `*`, but I don't know which columns you are actually interested in, from either the current or previous row.

Answer (score 1):

> lag function doesn't help in date datatype.

No, That's not right and you may be looking for something like this.

```
SELECT JOB_NAME,
  CASE
    WHEN REQ_START_DATE >= LAG ( actual_start_date + run_duration ) 
     OVER ( PARTITION BY JOB_NAME ORDER BY LOG_DATE )
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END
FROM dba_scheduler_job_run_details;
```

Answer (score 0):

Used below query to get the data of all the jobs whose differs in req_start_date and actual_start_date excluding those job's details which gets delayed because of previous job run delayed (i.e.  don't want to get alerted if the delayed start is due to previous run not completed)
and who is taking more than 60 secs

```
SELECT extract(DAY FROM(t.actual_start_date - t.req_start_date)) * 24 * 60 * 60 +
       (extract(hour FROM(t.actual_start_date - t.req_start_date))) * 60 * 60 +
       (extract(minute FROM(t.actual_start_date - t.req_start_date))) AS duration,
       t.*
FROM (SELECT d.*,
             lag(actual_start_date) over(PARTITION BY job_name ORDER BY req_start_date) AS lag_actual_start_date,
             lag(run_duration) over(PARTITION BY job_name ORDER BY req_start_date) AS lag_run_duration
      FROM dba_scheduler_job_run_details d) t
WHERE ((lag_actual_start_date IS NOT NULL AND req_start_date > lag_actual_start_date + lag_run_duration) OR -- For Jobs running at frequent time interval
      (lag_actual_start_date IS NULL AND actual_start_date > req_start_date))        -- For Jobs scheduled at single time interval
AND extract(DAY FROM(t.actual_start_date - t.req_start_date)) * 24 * 60 * 60 +
      (extract(hour FROM(t.actual_start_date - t.req_start_date))) * 60 * 60 +
      (extract(minute FROM(t.actual_start_date - t.req_start_date))) > 1
ORDER BY log_date DESC;
```